# Tumblr control buttons (reblog,dashboard etc.) missing for theme

Tags: javascript, html, button, themes, tumblr

I have pasted my theme code before tweaking here, it's a redux edit.http://pastebin.com/vWfbZVJy

So recently I've decided to tweak my theme. My theme code after tweaking contains lots of options like bigger sidebar, smaller and the like.

But recently I've just begun to noice that my Tumblr control buttons aka 'customize' for me and 'follow,dashboard,like,reblog' at the upper corners have dissapeared. I googled it up and apparently this happens a lot when editing a redux theme. Somebody has posted a solution here
http://peruseporisu.tumblr.com/post/54259402935/tumblr-control-buttons-fix but it doesn't work for me at all.

So I went to see the theme code that i pasted (up there, the pastebin link) and saw that it didn't have any #tumblrcontrol or anything.

And I'm trying to create and publish a theme so the advice won't work as what do i put for the URL to make it available not only for me, but for other people who use this theme too?

Comment: The problem (usually) lies in how much memory is currently being used by the browser page and generally, requires a flush of the page cache by closing and reopening the page or even closing and reopening the browser. I honestly don't know another way to get around it, but I run into this problem a lot and not just on Redux themes.

Comment: I had this same problem, view my answer here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130456/tumblr-missing-follow-dashboard-customize-control-buttons-not-showing-in/23130457#23130457