# Tumblr - Missing Follow, Dashboard & Customize control buttons - not showing in top right corner

Tags: tumblr

### Problem

I'm trying to figure out why tumblr is not showing me the `iframe#tumblr_controls` (which holds the `follow`, `dashboard` or `customize` (if logged in) buttons) *(view pics below).*

I am using a theme I purchased directly from tumblr and have customized it heavily, there are no html or javascript errors.

I've found a few answers to style the following buttons, but I don't see them in my div.

#### Normal Users see:

[image: User]

#### Admin (logged in) Users see:

[image: Admin]

I dont see any of the two buttons above on tumblr, any ideas why its not showing?

I also have another issue where I am using the following template tags and HTML to render tumblr share buttons, but the buttons are not clickable (they are iframes with divs inside).

```
<!-- Im including share buttons like this, but the "Like btn" is not clickable ->
<div id="tumblr-share">
    <ul class="tumblr-action">
        <li class="reblog">{ReblogButton size="20" color="grey"}</li>
        <li class="like">{LikeButton size="20" color="grey"}</li>
        <li class="notes"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas why my tumblr share buttons and follow, dashboard & customize buttons are not showing in the top right corner like all other blogs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

After some researching and asking around (thanks to @[PHPology](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383633/phpology)), I figured out that this was an issue because my blog was marked as "private" (password protected) in tumblr settings.

[image: Password Protected]

Make sure your blog is not password protected, else the buttons will not show/work as expected.

Also ensure your HTML is valid and correct and there are no javascript errors (tumblr loads these buttons in dynamically via javascript after page load - Javascript errors will stop the execution of this script and others).

---

#### Customizing the like button hover

A great post here on how to apply hover effects to the like and reblog buttons within the iframe.

[Customise Tumblr's *new* Like Button iFrame {LikeButton}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708662/customise-tumblrs-new-like-button-iframe-likebutton/21715659#21715659)

Comment: Just to add to this. You can enable / disable the Tumblr Controls. Customize > Advanced Options > Promote Tumblr!.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried copying and pasting code in various places (there was one right after `<body>` and one right before `</style>`) but neither of those worked for me, so as a last resort I ended up copying and pasting the code for the entire theme in again and that worked (but it did erase all my customizations so this really is a last resort).